# Why does each model in my collection have a collection?

Tags: backbone.js, model

The returned json is as expected but when i console.log the response i get this mad structure that seems to go on forever. Each of my models is gaining a collection of the exact collection it itself is part of. What on earth is going on?

Heres the code im calling it with

```
        this.reporterCollection.fetch({
            success: _.bind(function(response){
                console.log("response");
                console.log(response);
                this.addChildView(new DirectReportListView({collection: response, supervisor: this.searchAlias, projectId: this.options.projectId}).render(), $("#testModalDiv"));
            }, this)
        });
```

Ignore the view stuff, the problem occurs before on the log line.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal, each `model` in a collection have a `collection` field that points to the `collection` containing it.

> The model.collection property is normally created automatically when you first add a model to a collection.

[Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor)

Comment: Thanks, i realise its just a pointer now, i thought the model was actually containing a collection of itself.